# Root cannot move files

Tags: debian, sudo, mv

I'm on Debian 5, I want to move files, but I'm getting a permission denied error, even if I'm root.

Do you have any solutions?

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 scusr scusr 49901 Jun 17 09:04 flux_outfacture_130617090229UN_Test_888880617014310001.pdf

$ mv flux_outfacture_130617090229UN_Test_888880617014310001.pdf flux_out/facture_130617090229UN_Test_888880617014310001.pdf
```

> mv: cannot move
>   `flux_outfacture_130617090229UN_Test_888880617014310001.pdf' to`
>   flux_out/facture_130617090229UN_Test_888880617014310001.pdf':
>   Permission denied

Comment: Is the directory NFS-mounted or mounted read-only?

Comment: What is the output of `lsattr -d flux_out` ? What is the output of `ls -ld flux_out` ?

Comment: Just a reminder, stop using debian 5 and migrate as soon as you can : "Debian GNU/Linux 5.0 has been superseded by Debian 6.0 ("squeeze"). Security updates have been discontinued as of February 6th, 2012"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you in a NFS share? then depending on how that server is configured you might get root squashed. This may also apply to other remotely mounted file systems.

If nfs, check if the fs is exported with the `root_squash` option, or else if it is mounted with the `no_root_squash` (to allow root to remain root even when accessing the exported fs)

from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_security#Root_squash):

> Root squash[2][3] is reduction of the access rights for the remote superuser (root) when using identity authentication (local user is the same as remote user). It is primarily the feature of NFS but potentially may be available on other systems as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes i am on a NFS share.

Comment: Here is the result of lsattr -d flux_out
lsattr -d flux_out
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on flux_out

I can cp files in flux_out, but i can't move or delete files in the sources directory.

How can i know is there is the root_squash option ?

Comment: On some systems `showmount -e` on the NFS server will show options. I'd double check with `man showmount` first though to verify ...